# What is this line in my ceiling where the wall meets?

Tags: ceiling

What is this line in my ceiling where the wall meets?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the joint of the ceiling panels with deformed joining tape.

Comment: Is it dangerous at all, or cause any leaks? @r13

Comment: It is more a defect in looks, than structural.  Most houses have had them and happens as a new house(about 5 years) settlers.  Repair to fix is easy, but matching it to look like the rest can be hard depending on age.

Comment: As noted in your previous questions, a ceiling neither creates nor prevents leaks. It's there to look nice, & if insulated above, prevent heat loss into any roof space above. It is not in any way waterproof in itself.

Answer (score 2):

If there were leaks you'd usually see staining.

I think it's tape coming loose because it was originally not applied wet enough (with "tape" we mean drywall mesh or paper tape, not sticky tape)

To fix, strip off the loose tape, scrape off some surrounding plaster/mud and apply new corner tape, and re-plaster with the same pattern.

Alternatively, apply crown molding. The tape is only required for aesthetics, it is not functional.